# Reduction from a language with unknown decidability to HALT

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, halting-problem, turing-recognizable

We were taught to use reductions in order to show that a given L is undecidable. My question is, given some definition of a new L, is there a way to find a reduction
$$
L\leq_mHALT
$$
So that I can determine $L \in RE$?
More specifically, given the quite common problem of the decidability of
$$
L=\{\langle M\rangle | |L(M)| ≥ 5\}
$$
(Or any other natural number instead of 5)

All proofs I've seen online construct a TM that uses dovetailing so I was wondering if there is a different way to solve this problem, specifically using a reduction.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reduction from the proofs you've seen. Construct a TM $M_L$ which uses dovetailing to count how many inputs a given TM $M$ accepts and let $M_L$ halt once that counter reaches a value $\geq 5$. Thus, $M_L$ halts on input $\langle M \rangle$ if and only if $\langle M \rangle \in L$, yielding the desired reduction.

I don't see an easier reduction for this problem.